# RuntimeError: invalid argument 10: ldb should be at least max(1, 0), but have 0

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, linear-regression

I am trying a Linear Regression algorithm with Federated learning using Pytorch and I face the following error.

> RuntimeError: invalid argument 10: ldb should be at least max(1, 0), but have 0

I am implementing it on Colab. This error might be due to some code line in the def federated_learning (diagnosis_title, hospital_features, hospital_targets, test_input, test_output) function.

This is the code:

```
def federated_learning(diagnosis_title, hospital_features, hospital_targets, test_input, test_output):
model = LogisticRegression()
criterion = th.nn.BCELoss(size_average=True)
optimizer = th.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)  
losses = [[] for i in range(n_hospitals)]
accuracies = [[] for i in range(n_hospitals)]
for iteration in range(iterations):
    models = [model.copy().send(hospitals[i]) for i in range(n_hospitals)]
    optimizers = [th.optim.SGD(params = models[i].parameters(), lr = learning_rate) for i in range(n_hospitals)]
    for worker_iteration in range(worker_iterations):
        last_losses = []
        for i in range(n_hospitals):
            optimizers[i].zero_grad()
            prediction = models[i](hospital_features[i])
            
            loss = criterion(prediction, hospital_targets[i].detach())
            loss.backward()
            optimizers[i].step()
            loss = loss.get().data.item()
            last_losses.append(loss)
    for i in range(n_hospitals):
        losses[i].append(last_losses[i])
        train_acc = compute_federated_accuracy(models[i], hospital_features[i], hospital_targets[i])
        accuracies[i].append(train_acc)
        models[i].move(secure_worker)
    with th.no_grad():
        avg_weight = sum([models[i].linear.weight.data for i in range(n_hospitals)]) / n_hospitals
        model.linear.weight.set_(avg_weight.get())
        avg_bias = sum([models[i].linear.bias.data for i in range(n_hospitals)]) / n_hospitals
        model.linear.bias.set_(avg_bias.get())
    if iteration % 100 == 0:
        losses_str = ['{:.4f}'.format(losses[i][-1]) for i in range(n_hospitals)]
        accuracies_str = [to_percent(accuracies[i][-1]) for i in range(n_hospitals)]
        print('Iteration={}, losses={}, accuracies={}'.format(iteration, losses_str, accuracies_str))
plot_federated_graphs(diagnosis_title, losses, accuracies)
plot_federated_graphs1(diagnosis_title, losses, accuracies)

test_acc = compute_accuracy(model, test_input, test_output)
print('\nTesting Accuracy = {}'.format(to_percent(test_acc)))
```

Error comes in loss.backward() statement.

Error is shown when I call the function:

```
----> 2 model = federated_learning(diagnosis_title1, hospital_featuresa, hospital_targets1a, test_input, test_output1)
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe use `print()` to see what you have in variables in line which makes problem - maybe it helps to see problem.

Comment: Could you please copy the entire error message in your question? because I need to know in which line in the federated_learning function the error.